# Given topological space X, t, is there an elegant way to express Int(X), the interior of X?

Tags: general-topology

Given the topological space X, t, is there an elegant way to express Int(X), the interior of X - the entire space?
I know one way: Int(X) = $\bigcup Fi$ where $Fi$ is an open set in X. 
But this comes by definition. Is there a way using other derived sets, like closure, frontier, exterior, and weak derived set?

Comment: Are you aware that $\operatorname{Int}(X)=X$? What could be simpler or more elegant than that?

Comment: For any subset $A$ of $X$, $\operatorname{int}(A)= X\setminus \overline{X\setminus \overline{A}}$. Also $\operatorname{int}(A) = \overline{A}\setminus \operatorname{Fr}(A)$.

Comment: @MJD Then, how would you consider Fr(X), frontier of X. The definition in my book reads: Fr(A) = {x | each open set which contains x contains points of both A and X - A}. Obviously, X-X = 0, so what is the standard answer for this question?

Comment: Yes, when $X$ is a space, $\operatorname{Fr}(X) =\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, $X$ is an open subset of $X$, when we take the union $\bigcup U_i$ over all open $U_i\subseteq X$, we get $\bigcup U_i=X$. Hence $\mathrm{Int}\left(X\right)=X$.

Answer (score 2):

In case it's not clear from the other answers: Go check any definition of a topological space. One of the requirement is that both $X$ and the empty set *must* be open sets -- otherwise it's not a topological space. So, using your notation, one of the $F_i$ is $X$, so the union is $X$. Which explains MJD's statement that $int(X) = X$.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if what's confusing you is this: to talk about the interior of a set (or the closure, boundary, or frontier) we must talk about it **in relation to some topology**.  Often, we leave the topology implicit, but it's always there, lurking in the background, and we can't ignore it completely.  This is one of those times we cannot ignore it.

Consider a circle ($S^1$).  Does it have a boundary?  Considered as a space by itself, it has no boundary, because you can walk around and around the circle forever and never get to an end.

But considered as a subset of the plane, *every* point of the circle is a boundary point:  The circle bounds a disc and when you stand on a point of the circle you can step off into the disc or out of the disc.

An interior is always an open set.  But the meaning of “open” depends on the topology.  And a set open in one topology might not be open in another.  Consider:

1. $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology
2. $[0,\infty)$ with the subspace topology inherited from $\Bbb R$
3. $[0,1]\cup [2,3]$ with the subspace topology inherited from $\Bbb R$

In spaces 1 and 2, the set $[0,1]$ is not open.  But in space 3, it is.  (You should check the definition.)

When you consider $[0,1]$ as a subset of space 1, its interior is $(0,1)$, which is open in space 1.   Its boundary has two points, $\{0, 1\}$.

When you consider $[0,1]$ as a subset of space 2, its interior is $[0,1)$, which is open in space 2.  The boundary has only one point, $\{1\}$.

When you consider $[0,1]$ as a subset of space 3, its interior is $[0,1]$, which is open in space 3.  The boundary is empty.